# What are the eigenvalues of the $n\times n$ matrix $xy^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x$ and $y$ be two non-zero $n\times 1$ vectors. What are the eigenvalues of the $n\times n$ matrix $xy^T$?

I have one more doubt in the same question  here $x$ be a $n\times 1$ matrix so how many eigenvalues it has??

I tried in many ways but I stuck from the starting point also??

Comment: Only square matrices have eigenvalues, right? Try a few examples (say, with $n=2$ and $n=3$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $xy^{T}u=\lambda u$ and $u \neq 0$. This gives $\sum x_iy_ju_j=\lambda u_i$. Multiply both sides by $y_i$ and sum over $i$. You get $(\sum y_ix_i) (\sum y_ju_j)=\lambda \sum y_iu_i$. If $\sum y_ju_j \neq 0$ this gives $\lambda =\sum y_ix_i$. If $\sum y_ju_j = 0$ then the previous equation shows $\lambda =0$. Hence there are only two possible eigen values: $0$ and $\sum y_ix_i$.

For $n>1$, $0$ is surely an eigen value since there is always a nonzero vector orthogonal to $y$.

Comment: Sorry sir I didn't get can u please explain little bit more precisely

Comment: $A=xy^{T}$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. By definition $u$ is an eigen vector with eigen value $\lambda$ if $\sum a_{ij}u_j=\lambda u_i$ for all $i$ and $u \neq 0$. Note that $a_{ij}=x_iy_j$. Is the rest clear now?

Comment: SIr the above part is clear now can you please explain the rest also like wise...Sorry sir I am disturbing u

Comment: The case $\sum y_j u_j \neq 0$ is simple. If $\sum y_j u_j = 0$ you get $\sum x_i y_j u_j=\lambda u_i$ and LHS is $x_i (\sum y_j u_j)=0$. So we get $\lambda u_i=0$ and this is true for all $i$. Since $u$ is  a non-zero vector this implies $\lambda =0$.

Comment: Sir in the first case how it equals $\sum y_ju_j$ and $\sum y_iu_i$ because the sum over $i$

Comment: When you multiply by $y_i$ and sum over $i$, $\sum_j y_ju_j$ is a constant and it cones out of sum over $i$.

Comment: Oh God...I got it Super Sir....Thank you Sir